# How can I send the value of fuction(data) instead of sending it into $("#timer")?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

How can I send the value of `function(data)` instead of sending it into `$("#timer")`?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type= "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

function update() {
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'serverTime.php',
   timeout: 1000,
   success: function(data) {
      $("#timer").html(data); 
      window.setTimeout(update, 10);
   }
  });
 }
 update();

});
</script>
<div id="timer"> </div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please clarify where you wish to "*send the value of `function(data)`*." It would also be best to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour